# Log4php wrong time

Tags: php, logging, log4php

I'm a new user of log4php and I have a problem with the time.
The time logged in the log file is late of 2 hours compared with the real time.
My configuration file contains:

`<
layout class="LoggerLayoutPattern">
                    <
param name="conversionPattern" value="%-5level %date{Y-m-d H:i:s,u} %logger %msg%n" />
    <
/layout>`

My configuration:

- apache-log4php-2.3.0
- WampServer 2.4 -x64
- windows 7 64 bits

How can I get the correct time ?
Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: Timezone settings perhaps...!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set a timezone in your php script?

You can set it like:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

Or you can set it on the server in the php.ini or .htaccess files as shown in the following article.
[How to set a timezone on your PHP server.](http://codingpad.maryspad.com/2012/03/19/setting-the-time-zone-for-php-5-3-x/)

Comment: Thanks for your response :) But actually, I noticed that the apache.log in wamp has the same problem. So I guess that it's a problem with the Wamp configuration. I will take a look at it.